# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception even after exception handling Android

Tags: java, android, exception, file-handling

So I am populating a grid view in a fragment, and, I have a spinner where folder options are listed

[image: This is the Gallery Fragment with the spinner]

and whenever I choose a folder with no files, the app crashes giving an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                         Process: manika.aditya.ekayana, PID: 13405
                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                       at manika.aditya.ekayana.Share.GalleryFragment.setupGridView(GalleryFragment.java:170)
                                                                       at manika.aditya.ekayana.Share.GalleryFragment.access$300(GalleryFragment.java:37)
                                                                       at manika.aditya.ekayana.Share.GalleryFragment$3.onItemSelected(GalleryFragment.java:142)
```

this is the function that I wrote to populate the GridView

and as you can observe, it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception

```
private void setupGridView(String selectedDirectory) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupGridView: directory chosen: " + selectedDirectory);
    final ArrayList<String> imgURLs = FileSearch.getFilePaths(selectedDirectory);

    //set the grid column width
    int gridWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int imageWidth = gridWidth/NUM_GRID_COLUMNS;
    gridView.setColumnWidth(imageWidth);

    //use the grid adapter to adapter the images to gridview
    GridImageAdapter adapter = new GridImageAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_grid_imageview, mAppend, imgURLs);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //set the first image to be displayed when the activity fragment view is inflated

    try{

        setImage(imgURLs.get(0), galleryImage, mAppend);

    }

    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe){}

    mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(0);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected an image: " + imgURLs.get(position));

            setImage(imgURLs.get(position), galleryImage, mAppend);
            mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(position);
        }
    });

}
```

even the function call is enclosed in a try and catch block that again catches an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception

```
try{

                setupGridView(directories.get(position));
            }

            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe)  { }

        }
```

this is the directories/file search method, just in case

```
directories = new ArrayList<>();
```

the file path function

```
 public static ArrayList<String> getFilePaths(String directory){
    ArrayList<String> pathArray = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File(directory);
    File[] listfiles = file.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < listfiles.length; i++){
        if(listfiles[i].isFile()){
            pathArray.add(listfiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    return pathArray;
}
```

}

and the file path class

```
public class FilePaths {

//"storage/emulated/0"
public String ROOT_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

public String PICTURES = ROOT_DIR + "/Pictures";
public String CAMERA = ROOT_DIR + "/DCIM/camera";

public String FIREBASE_IMAGE_STORAGE = "photos/users/";
```

}

Comment: in which line you are getting this exception?

Comment: It's in the Log I've posted

Comment: what do you think that `mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(0);` does? (hint: follow the stacktrace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting index from imgURLS check imgURLS has some values in it.

```
if(imgURLs.size()>0){              
    try{


                        setImage(imgURLs.get(0), galleryImage, mAppend);



                    mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(0);
                    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected an image: " + imgURLs.get(position));

                            setImage(imgURLs.get(position), galleryImage, mAppend);
                            mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(position);
                        }
                    });

             catch (Exception EX){
            }
    }
else{
//No image url
}
```

}

Comment: Problem Solved ! `final ArrayList<String> imgURLs = FileSearch.getFilePaths(selectedDirectory);
        IMGurlSize = imgURLs.size();
` and then I did exactly as you said, well, I added a Toast in the else statement

Comment: why do you think you need a try ... catch?

Comment: just in case any exception arise while setImage or onClick of image

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this

```
try{

    setImage(imgURLs.get(0), galleryImage, mAppend);

}

catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe){}

mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(0);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected an image: " + imgURLs.get(position));

        setImage(imgURLs.get(position), galleryImage, mAppend);
        mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(position);
    }
});
```

into this

```
try{
    setImage(imgURLs.get(0), galleryImage, mAppend);
    mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(0);
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe){}

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected an image: " + imgURLs.get(position));
            setImage(imgURLs.get(position), galleryImage, mAppend);
            mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(position);
        } 
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe){}
    }
});
```

Comment: still the same error `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: manika.aditya.ekayana, PID: 20316
                                                                       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                           `

Comment: asking for forgiveness instead of permission is well considered in python, less so in Java. Exceptions are expensive, so consider testing your conditions instead of try ... catching.